# Show all options on refinement panel

Tags: refinement-panel

I have search page where I placed refinement panel. My client wants to see all options on refinement panel when page is loaded and he wants to remove a link "Show more".

How I can achieve this result?

Comment: what all options?? refinement panel shows managed properties

Answer (score 0):

The way I did is updated the value of `shortListSize` variable in `Filter_Default.html` file to cover all options. The file is in `Master Page Gallery` -> `Display Templates` -> `Filters`.

For my case, I changed it from 5 to 15.